# Spring Boot convert (load image from jsp) to (load from html)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I got an old project which is using Strut1 framework. So it uses JSP to load captcha image from another JSP file. Source code below.

Now, I upgrade that project using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf layout. I don't know how to convert it into html. Please take a look and give ideas.

Thanks.

**For login.jsp**

```
<div id="captcha" style="cursor: pointer; height: 30px; width: 150px; display: inline-block; float: left"><img src="captcha.jsp"></div>
```

**captcha.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.awt.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.awt.image.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.imageio.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.awt.geom.*"%>
<%@ page import="vn.com.tivn.online.acquiring.util.ValueUtil"%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>captcha</title>
</head>
<body>

<%
 //========================================================
 // Kick Ass Captcha JSP
 //
 // Michael Connor 2007
 //
 // I just couldn't handle the thought of downloading a
 // big jar and configuring some servlet.xml and having
 // little to no control of anything...
 // You can send in height and width parameters.
 // The captcha value will be placed in the session in
 // a parameter called 'captcha'
 //
 // Feel free to use this code and do whatever the hell
 // you want to it.
 //========================================================

  String imageFormat = "png";
  response.setContentType("image/" + imageFormat);

 try {
   // you can pass in fontSize, width, height via the request

   Color backgroundColor = Color.blue;
   Color borderColor = Color.black;
   Color textColor = Color.white;
   Color circleColor = new Color(160,160,160);
   Font textFont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, paramInt(request, "fontSize", 24));
   int charsToPrint = 6;
   int width = paramInt(request, "width", 150);
   int height = paramInt(request, "height", 30);
   int circlesToDraw = 6;
   float horizMargin = 20.0f;
   float imageQuality = 0.95f; // max is 1.0 (this is for jpeg)
   double rotationRange = 0.7; // this is radians
   BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

   Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bufferedImage.getGraphics();

   g.setColor(backgroundColor);
   g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

   // lets make some noisey circles
   g.setColor(circleColor);
   for ( int i = 0; i < circlesToDraw; i++ ) {
     int circleRadius = (int) (Math.random() * height / 2.0);
     int circleX = (int) (Math.random() * width - circleRadius);
     int circleY = (int) (Math.random() * height - circleRadius);
     g.drawOval(circleX, circleY, circleRadius * 2, circleRadius * 2);
   }

   g.setColor(textColor);
   g.setFont(textFont);

   FontMetrics fontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics();
   int maxAdvance = fontMetrics.getMaxAdvance();
   int fontHeight = fontMetrics.getHeight();

   // i removed 1 and l and i because there are confusing to users...
   // Z, z, and N also get confusing when rotated
   // 0, O, and o are also confusing...
   // lowercase G looks a lot like a 9 so i killed it
   // this should ideally be done for every language...
   // i like controlling the characters though because it helps prevent confusion
   String elegibleChars = "ABCDEFGHJKLMPQRSTUVWXYabcdefhjkmnpqrstuvwxy23456789";
   char[] chars = elegibleChars.toCharArray();

   float spaceForLetters = -horizMargin * 2 + width;
   float spacePerChar = spaceForLetters / (charsToPrint - 1.0f);

   AffineTransform transform = g.getTransform();

   StringBuffer finalString = new StringBuffer();

   for ( int i = 0; i < charsToPrint; i++ ) {
     double randomValue = Math.random();
     int randomIndex = (int) Math.round(randomValue * (chars.length - 1));
     char characterToShow = chars[randomIndex];
     finalString.append(characterToShow);

     // this is a separate canvas used for the character so that
     // we can rotate it independently
     int charImageWidth = maxAdvance * 2;
     int charImageHeight = fontHeight * 2;
     int charWidth = fontMetrics.charWidth(characterToShow);
     int charDim = Math.max(maxAdvance, fontHeight);
     int halfCharDim = (int) (charDim / 2);

     BufferedImage charImage = new BufferedImage(charDim, charDim, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
     Graphics2D charGraphics = charImage.createGraphics();
     charGraphics.translate(halfCharDim, halfCharDim);
     double angle = (Math.random() - 0.5) * rotationRange;
     charGraphics.transform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(angle));
     charGraphics.translate(-halfCharDim,-halfCharDim);
     charGraphics.setColor(textColor);
     charGraphics.setFont(textFont);

     int charX = (int) (0.5 * charDim - 0.5 * charWidth);
     charGraphics.drawString("" + characterToShow, charX, 
                            (int) ((charDim - fontMetrics.getAscent()) 
                                   / 2 + fontMetrics.getAscent()));

     float x = horizMargin + spacePerChar * (i) - charDim / 2.0f;
     int y = (int) ((height - charDim) / 2);
//System.out.println("x=" + x + " height=" + height + " charDim=" + charDim + " y=" + y + " advance=" + maxAdvance + " fontHeight=" + fontHeight + " ascent=" + fontMetrics.getAscent());
     g.drawImage(charImage, (int) x, y, charDim, charDim, null, null);

     charGraphics.dispose();
   }

   // let's do the border
   g.setColor(borderColor);
   g.drawRect(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1);

   //Write the image as a jpg
   Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName(imageFormat);
   if( iter.hasNext() ) {
     ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter)iter.next();
     ImageWriteParam iwp = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
     if ( imageFormat.equalsIgnoreCase("jpg") || imageFormat.equalsIgnoreCase("jpeg") ) {
       iwp.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
       iwp.setCompressionQuality(imageQuality);
     }
     writer.setOutput(ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(response.getOutputStream()));
     IIOImage imageIO = new IIOImage(bufferedImage, null, null);
     writer.write(null, imageIO, iwp);
   } else {
     throw new RuntimeException("no encoder found for jsp");
   }

   // let's stick the final string in the session
   request.getSession().setAttribute("wirecardmposcaptcha", finalString.toString());
System.out.print("----------"+g.dispose());
   g.dispose();

 } catch (IOException ioe) {
   throw new RuntimeException("Unable to build image" , ioe);
 }

%>

<%!
  public static String paramString(HttpServletRequest request, String paramName, String defaultString) {
    return request.getParameter(paramName) != null ? request.getParameter(paramName) : defaultString;
  }

  public static int paramInt(HttpServletRequest request, String paramName, int defaultInt) {
    return request.getParameter(paramName) != null ? Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter(paramName)) : defaultInt;
  }

%>


<%
    if(ValueUtil.SUPPORT_SSL){
        String sessionid = request.getSession().getId();
        response.addHeader("SET-COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=" + sessionid + "; Secure; HttpOnly");
    }
%>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an inital approach:

1. Create a file under resources/templates folder called login.html and place the same code as in login.jsp. Replace `<img src="captcha.jsp">` by something like `<img th:src="${capchaUrl}">` If this is not an entire page you can also create a fragment and include it wherever you need.
2. In your template controller add the methods needed to create the captcha by refactoring captcha.jsp and, once you have the captcha, you can add it to the model like `model.addAttribute("capchaUrl", the_generated_captcha);` it should be populated in the template.

Comment: Thanks, let me try it.